# Difference between server time and outlook sent time while sending mail throug program

Tags: java, email, outlook

Through my java programe I am sending a mail to someone,
In the subject of mail I displayed curent server time e.g(on Wed May 28 **12:14:14** IST 2014)
But when I check my outlook the sent timing of the same mail(Wed 5/28/2014 **7:29 PM**) is so differ from mailling time,
Please give me some hint why this difference occur,
I am running java program on linux server.

Thanks

Comment: might be a lot of reasons. maybe that server has a wrong date/time configuration.

Comment: As I menton in my question server time is ok is diplay the correct   Wed May 28 12:14:14 IST 2014 but the timing in outlook is odd   Wed 5/28/2014 7:29 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook displays the time of the delivery-date in headers of the message. Check the computer time where outlook is installed. Also, in the message headers check the delivery-date.

Comment: Its installed at my local system and I am sending only a text mail without attachment and the time difference is approx 7:30 hour

Comment: yes, it might be because your mail exchange server is sending the delivery-date in email headers incorrectly. To check the headers, Right-click the message in Inbox > Message Options > Internet headers

Comment: Yup I checked Internet headers its showing wrong time,Would you please let me know how  can I fix it

Comment: oh, then its the problem of your exchange server. Contact your server administrator or some settings you'll have to change

Comment: Thanks For your help! Actually I had a discussion with my team and I came to know that this happen only with that mail which send through java program but with the other application like jenkins they are using same exchange server and the result is appropriate for jenkins